# Google Maps v2 - how to populate more than two TextViews in infowindowadapter?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Surprised I can't find the answer already, but I'm having a problem doing something very simple with the info window for Google Maps. I want to create a custom InfoWindow, with three pieces of text, one of which has customisable colour (depending on the text, but it would be nice to set this colour by passing in an argument instead when placing the marker). This was dead easy in v1, but totally messed up in v2 it seems.

In my main activity I have this part to add my custom layout to the InfoWindowAdapter:

```
class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{
    private final View myContentsView;

    MyInfoWindowAdapter(){
        myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        TextView textStationName = (TextView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.textStationName);
        textStationName.setText(marker.getTitle());

        TextView textAPI = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.textAPI));
        textAPI.setText(marker.getSnippet());

        return myContentsView;
    }   

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

I can get two pieces of text passed in when creating the marker, "Title" and "Snippet". But I have three pieces of text that I want to display there. And all the examples I have seen so far, are limited to two pieces of text - no way to get a third (or fourth, ...) element in.

I am using the v4-support library (using API version 8), and the how-to [given here](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.hk/2012/12/using-infowindowadapter-part-1.html) does not work for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could suggest to store the content for your map markers in a `Map<Marker, InfoWindowContent` in your activity, where `InfoWindowContent` is some class with fields to populate the info window for a marker.

After you added a marker to the map, `put` the marker with it's info window content to the `Map`. Then, in your info window content adapter, get marker's content from the `Map`.

Here is an example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private static class InfoWindowContent {
        public String text1;
        public String text2;
        public String text3;
        // ... add other fields if you need them
    }

    private Map<Marker, InfoWindowContent> markersContent = new HashMap<Marker, InfoWindowContent>();

    private void addMarker() {
        Marker marker = map.addMarker(...);
        InfoWindowContent markerContent = new InfoWindowContent();
        // ... populate content for the marker

        markersContent.put(marker, markerContent);
    }

    class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            InfoWindowContent markerContent = markersContent.get(marker);

            // ... populate info window with your content
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a fully worked example of this in the Google Play Services mapdemo samples -- see the MarkerDemoActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can place the additional informations as an `JSONObject` in the `Marker` and access it in the `getInfoContents` method like this

```
    JSONObject content = new JSONObject(marker.getSnippet());
    textView1.setText(content.getString("myFirstInfo"));
    textView2.setText(content.getString("mySecondInfo"));
```

Comment: Doesn't sound very java-like. And AFAIK JSON is primarily meant for transport of values between web services. Probably not the most efficient way.